# PHP: loop through an array give wrong result

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have following code:

```
$source_stat_array = array(0 => 'clicks', 1 => 'impr', 2 => 'spend');
$count = count($source_stat_array);


for ($i = 0; $i < count; $i++) {
    echo $source_stat_array[$i++];
}
```

the result i get is following:

```
clicks spend
```

instead of i need

```
clicks impr spend
```

can you answer me what is wrong with code?

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < count; $i++) {` its `$count` not `count`. No need to increment $i in loop, it will autoincrement. `echo $source_stat_array[$i++];` remove `++`

Comment: `$` missing in count in for loop

Comment: You could use a foreach http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/23fdf9a9fe13a8018dd00a9334fa7574538419fc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are incrementing the value of $i twice.
Try the below code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $source_stat_array[$i];
}
```

Comment: hi's right. now its work with [$i]

Comment: sorry...I missed the $..updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` it will iterate through each key

```
foreach($source_stat_array as $key => $value){
  echo $value;
}
```

Read more about `foreach` , [manual](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)